# How to confirm installations made in a docker container

Tags: docker, yum

I've got a docker container and i'm trying to install python. I'm using `yum` for it:

```
yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
```

=> NOTE that I using CentOS-8. I found other install tutorials online but they were with `dnf` which I don't have.

```
yum update
```

=> this returns a screen where you get the all-known prompt: `Total download size: 24 M
Is this ok [y/N]:`
but docker doesn't let me type anything here, he quit automatically leaving `Operation aborted.` instead of `y` or `n`. How can i confirm my installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that when you run

```
yum update -y
```

it automatically says `y` to all the questions asked, so i could install it this way.